# Rules to pronounce "cha-" words

Tags: pronunciation

I am puzzled on how to pronounce *cha-* words. For example, I know that "chameleon" or "chamomile" are pronounced with a hard "c" like in "camel", not with a soft "c" like in "change". "Charity", on the other hand, is pronounced as in "change".

Is there some rule to infer the correct pronunciation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there really isn’t.

If you know the languagethe word comes from, you can sometimes make a better guess, like *chorus* is from Greek, so it’s a **/k/** sound there.

But there isn’t really a hard and fast rule.  Usually, though, it’s like in *church*, so guess that way if you have to guess; the sound is **/tʃ/**.

Wait, I take that back.  There is one rule. Words beginning with *chr-* are always with a **/k/** sound. *chronological, chrysoprase, Chris*. So are words beginning with *chl-*, like  *chloroplast*.

The imported French word *chaise* has a softer sound, just a **/ʃ/**.

I suspect most (maybe all?) words beginning with *chy-* come from Greek, and so have a hard sound there.  They’re all uncommon and rare.  For example, *chyle* is **/kaɪl/**, < Fr. *chyle* (= Ital. *chilo*, Sp. *quilo*):-L. *chȳlus*, a. Gr. *χῡλός* juice (of plants, animals, decoctions).

Comment: Along the lines of *chaise*, don't forget *Chicago* and *chaps* (as in cowboy attire, not as in "fellows").

Comment: @mmyers: For many American speakers, "chaise" is a homophone of "chase", at least in its most common usage in the term "chaise longue", which I often hear rendered as "chase lounge". Sigh. For most, "chaps" is always [tʃæps].

Comment: @Jon Purdy: I actually can't remember ever having said the word "chaise" out loud. :)

Comment: @mmyers: Being well-versed in French is a distinct disadvantage sometimes. My earlier teens were filled with exasperated cries of "What the hell do you mean it's not pronounced that way in English?!"

Comment: There are also several "cha-" words from Hebrew used in English that are properly pronounced with the back of the throat, such as "challah."

Comment: @mskfisher - +1, but I would more likely give "Chutzpah" as an example.

Comment: @Moshe: I often hear *chutzpah* pronounced with /tʃ-/, whereas *challah* I’ve almost always heard with the more authentically Hebrew /x-/.  I would guess the difference is that *chutzpah* has become more widely known, and is used a lot by people with no exposure at all to Hebrew, whereas *challah* doesn’t stray so far from Jewish communities and their cultural environs.

Comment: @PLL - Yes, but those people are pronouncing it wrong then. ;-)